# Unrestricting a sub directory in robots.txt

Tags: sitemap

OK, currently we are restricting the directory /Assets/ from being indexed in our robots.txt. There is one directory under the /Assets/ directory that I want indexed (/Assets/product_labels/). Is there any way to allow this one directory, other than moving it to another directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put explicit `Disallow` for all files and folders that are 'siblings' to the folder you want to keep open.

```
Disallow: /Assets/Dir1
Disallow: /Assets/Dir2
Disallow: /Assets/DirN
Disallow: /Assets/File1
Disallow: /Assets/File1
Disallow: /Assets/FileN
```

Just leave the `/Assets/product_labels` out -- to allow it.

Generation of this list can be automated, but remember this has to be done for every new directory or file you keep under `Assets` that you want to disallow.

Of course, if you are good to move the `product_labels` out of `Assets` it will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

" This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field. The easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate directory, say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this directory: " --> Quoted from: www.robotstxt.org